# React-Native images are locally cached

Tags: image, caching, mobile, react-native

I am showing images on React-Native like this:

```
<Image source={{uri: 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/bucket/image.jpg'}} />
```

When I specifically clear the cache of my app, the new picture appears.

Is there a way to avoid caching my specific image?

Also, I would like to avoid adding a `?x=randomStr` at the end of the URL to force re-force download each time.

Why is react-native not using Etags or something smarter instead of only relying on an url?

Should I force refresh my remote assets at each app opening?

Comment: The cache control is only implemented for iOs. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have an Android

Comment: For Android there is no cache parameters for the Image object so, your solution sounds pretty good to me.